configure "vsftpd" for certificate revocation
Is there a way to provide vsftpd with CRL?
The man page does not seem to have any option for the same and neither googling helped.
Appreciate response.

bit confused what a certificate revocation list would have to do with an FTP server? It's the client who needs to get the CRLs from somewhere, they don't come to him through the FTP(s) connection.

@MarcusMüller: vsftpd, like many other TLS-based services, supports server-side validation of certificates sent by the client.

ah so this is about revocation of client certificates, not server certificates? Client certifcates rarely appear in CRLs, though.

@MarcusMüller - ish. We use OpenVPN with 3FA (sort of) and when a client gets revoked the CRLs on both our servers get updated. Over the years our CRLs have grown a bit ;)
